# How to change the traceback of a custom Exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception, trace, traceback

I'm trying to create a custom exception that is raised inside of a class. However, whenever I raise it, the traceback leads to the original 'raise' statement.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do

```
# Errors
class NotImplementedError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg=""):
        super().__init__(msg)

class ImplementationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        super().__init__(msg)
        
# Interface decorator class
class Interface:
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.cls = cls

    def __call__(self):
        return self.cls()

def implement(interface):
    if type(interface) != Interface:
        raise ImplementationError("Expected interface")
    
    interface = interface.cls

    def wrapper(cls):
        iKeys = interface.__dict__.keys()
        cKeys = cls.__dict__.keys()

        for iKey in iKeys:
            if iKey not in cKeys:
                msg = (f"'{iKey}' not implemented in {cls.__name__}")
                raise NotImplementedError(msg)
        
        return cls

    return wrapper

@Interface
class Shape:
    origin = None

    def area(self): pass
    def bounding_rect(self): pass

@implement(Shape)
class Square:
    pass
```

And this is the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Square:
  File "main.py", line 34, in wrapper
    raise NotImplementedError(msg)
__main__.NotImplementedError: 'origin' not implemented in Square
```

Instead of the traceback leading to line 8, I want it to only lead to line 14 like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Square:
__main__.NotImplementedError: 'origin' not implemented in Square
```

Is this possible?

I tried googling it and didn't find anything helpful.

Edit:
I would also like to get rid of the `__main__.` in the last line of the stack trace if possible.

Comment: Shouldn't Test1 inherit from Exception or CustomException?

Comment: No, the test classes are completely separate from the Exception class. What I'm currently working on has more stuff going on but this is just a simple example. When Test1 raises the exception, I want it to reduce the traceback so it doesn't show Test1 and Test2 but only where the variable 'test' was instantiated.

Comment: Hmm, could you write a bit more _why_ you want to do that? What exact the goal of traceback editing? what do you want to hide?

Comment: I'm trying to implement interfaces into python using decorators and instead of showing the entire traceback, I want it show a portion of it. I'm going to edit the original post to include the actual code and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer (though not very elegant)

```
try:
    raise ImplementationError("Expected interface")
except ImplementationError as e:
    frame = e.__traceback__.tb_frame.f_back
    tb = e.__traceback__.__class__(None, frame, frame.f_lasti, frame.f_lineno)

    traceback.print_exception(e, e, tb)
    exit()
```